# Facing issues while trying to deploy app using Flask and Gunicorn (Never did before)

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, nlp, gunicorn

I am facing a problem here, want to deploy this Integrated_app.py to server. Please take a look at the code below, its only Flask code works fine, but when i did some changes for gunicorn to run, it is giving me errors.

```
import sys
import os
import json
from glob import glob
import string
from text_segregation.dl_text_seg import dl_text_seg
from text_segregation.utils.read_input import text_seg_read_docx_and_pdf
from json_to_txt import *
from education_details import *
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from work_experience_extraction.comparision import *
from work_experience_extraction.Work_Experience import *
from work_experience_extraction.work_exp_new.testing import *

class text_seg:
    def __init__(self):
        sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        current_dir = current_dir if current_dir is not '' else '.'
        self.data_dir_path = current_dir + '/text_segregation/data/resume_to_parse/resumeparser/' # directory to scan for any pdf and docx files
        self.parser = dl_text_seg()
        self.parser.load_model('./text_segregation' + '/models')

    def main(self):
        
        collected = text_seg_read_docx_and_pdf(self.data_dir_path, verbose =False, callback=lambda index, file_path, file_content: {
            parse_resume(index,file_path, file_content)
        })
        print(collected)
        print('count: ', len(collected))

    def parse_resume(self,index,file_path, file_content):
        print('parsing file: ', file_path)
        self.parser.parse(file_content)
        #print(self.parser.raw_text)  # print out the raw contents extracted from pdf or docx files
        parsed_info = { }
        parsed_info = self.parser.return_parsed_resume()
        # print(parsed_info,"1111111111111111111111111111111")                        # Printing json file on terminal

        #===========================saving json file=============================
        pre, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        # print("----------------",pre,ext,"--------------------------------2222")
        #pre = pre.replace(" ", "")
        with open(pre + '.json',"w") as json_file:
            json.dump(parsed_info, json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
        print("Parsed data saved in: ", pre + '.json')
        print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

###########************----------________per_info_extraction__________----------************############
import warnings, os
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*do not.*',)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import cv2
#import sys
import re
from rasa.nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa.nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa.nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa.nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter
from rasa.nlu import config
from rasa.nlu.components import ComponentBuilder
import json
from parsing_data import *
from format_work_exp import *
from work_json_to_txt import *

class per_info:
    def __init__(self):
        self.allowed_extensions = ['.txt']
        self.builder = ComponentBuilder(use_cache=True)
        self.interpreter = Interpreter.load('./per_info_extraction/Rasa_NLU/models/nlu/per_info_extaction', self.builder)

    def parse_resume(self, file_path):
        pre, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        print("Reading file: ",file_path)
        if ext in self.allowed_extensions:
            with open(pre + '.txt', 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
        #===================Entities extraction code============================
        print(pre,'ppppppppppppppppperrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssnnnnnnnnnaaaaaaaaalllllll')
        
        #table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation)) 
        #text = text.translate(table)
        parsed_by_rules = all_field(text)
        new_text = Punctuation(text)       
        
        js = self.interpreter.parse(new_text)
        js.update(parsed_by_rules)
        #####################################################formate###################################################
        list_per = js["entities"]
        first_name=""
        last_name = ""
        cur_ads = ""
        curr_city = ""
        curr_pin = ""
        per_add = ""
        per_pin = ""
        per_pin = ""
        per_city = ""
        for i in list_per:
            if i["entity"]=="first_name":
                first_name = i["value"]
            # else: first_name = None
            elif i["entity"]=="last_name":
                last_name = i["value"]
            # else: last_name = None
            elif i["entity"]=="current_address":
                cur_ads = i["value"]
            # else: cur_ads = None
            elif i["entity"]=="current_city":
                curr_city = i["value"]
            # else: curr_city = None
            elif i["entity"]=="current_pincode":
                curr_pin = i["value"]
            # else: curr_pin = None
            elif i["entity"]=="permanent_address":
                per_add = i["value"]
            elif i["entity"]=="permanent_pincode":
                per_pin = i["value"]
            elif i["entity"]=="permanent_city":
                per_city = i["value"]
            else:
                first_name=""
                last_name = ""
                cur_ads = ""
                curr_city = ""
                curr_pin = ""
                per_add = ""
                per_pin = ""
                per_pin = ""
                per_city = ""

        alter_email=js['alternate_email']
        dob=js['dob']
        email=js['email']
        gender=js['gender']
        mari_status=js['marital_status']
        if js['mobile_or_phone'] != None:
                if len(js['mobile_or_phone'])>1:
                    Phone=js['mobile_or_phone'][0]
                    mobile=js['mobile_or_phone'][1]
                else:
                    Phone=js['mobile_or_phone'][0]
                    mobile=None
        else:
            Phone=None 
            mobile=None
        text_per=js['text']
        ##################################################end#############################################################


        # print(js,"<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<persional_info>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        #===========================saving json file=============================

        with open(pre + '.json',"w") as json_file:
            json.dump(js, json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
        print("Entities and Intents extracted and saved in: ", pre + '.json')
        return {"FirstName":first_name,"LastName":last_name,"DateOfBirth":dob,"Gender":gender,"MaritalStatus":mari_status,"Email":email,"AlternateEmail":alter_email,"Phone":Phone,"Mobile":mobile,"Address":cur_ads,"City":curr_city,"ZipCode":curr_pin,"PermanentAddress":per_add,"PermanentCity":per_city,"PermanentZipCode":per_pin,"Text":text_per}
###########************----------________per_info_extraction__________----------************############
class work_ex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.allowed_extensions = ['.txt']
        self.builder = ComponentBuilder(use_cache=True)
        # self.interpreter = Interpreter.load('./work_experience_extraction/models/nlu/Invoice_details_extaction_backup', self.builder)

    def parse_work_data(self, file_path):
        pre, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        print("Reading file: ",file_path)
        if ext in self.allowed_extensions:
            with open(pre + '.txt', 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
        work_exp_text={}
        final_work_dict={}
        work_exp_text['Experience']=text
        js=line_spliting_function(text)


        # js = self.interpreter.parse(text)
        # print(js,"maaaaaaaaaaaaaattttttthhhhhhhhhhaaaaaaaaaaaannnnnnnnnnnnn")
        # jscode=extract_work_exp_details(text)
        # print(jscode,"sssssssssssssssssuuuuuuuuuuuuuuurrrrrrrrrrbbbbbbbbbbbhhhhhi")
        

        # print(js,"\n\n woooooooooo<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n\n")
        # with open(pre + '.json',"w") as json_file:
        #     json.dump(js, json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
        # final_js=work_exp_format(js,text)
        # json_work=comparision_file(jscode,final_js) 
        # print(json_work,"\n\nworkkkkkkkkexpppppppppppeeeeeeeeee\n\n")

        work_exp_text.update(js)
        final_work_dict["work_experience"]=work_exp_text
        
        with open(pre + '.json',"w") as json_file:
            json.dump(final_work_dict["work_experience"], json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
        return work_exp_text['Experience'],js['SegregatedExperience']

def education_parse(file_path):
    pre, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    print("Reading file: ",file_path)
    allowed_extensions=['.txt']
    if ext in allowed_extensions:
        with open(pre + '.txt', 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
    result_edu=extract_education_details(text)
    # print(result_edu,"<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<education detail>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    with open(pre + '.json',"w") as json_file:
            json.dump(result_edu, json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
    return result_edu






import time
start = time.time()
print("hello there")
end = time.time()
print("Initial time:",end - start)

# start = time.time()
# seg_my_text = text_seg()
# personal_info = per_info()
# work_exp=work_ex()
# end = time.time()
# print("Model loading time:",end - start)

global graph
import tensorflow as tf
#graph = tf.get_default_graph() 

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify
import random 
import operator 
import os
from flask_cors import CORS
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
# print(app)
# CORS(app)
# api = Api(app)
# print(api)
# app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False

import keras
#import tensorflow as tf
#session = keras.backend.get_session()
#init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
#session.run(init)


#seg_my_text = text_seg()
#personal_info = per_info()
#work_exp=work_ex()
#import tensorflow as tf
#graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# print("enjoy!")
# start = time.time()
# seg_my_text = text_seg()
# personal_info = per_info()
# work_exp=work_ex()
# end = time.time()
# print("Model loading time:",end - start)

class process(Resource):
    @app.route('/process', methods=['POST','PUT'])
    def __init__(self):
        print("enjoy!")
        self.start = time.time()
        self.seg_my_text = text_seg()
        self.personal_info = per_info()
        self.work_exp=work_ex()
        self.end = time.time()
        print("Model loading time:",self.end - self.start)

    
    def post():
        print("Step 1_"*5,"Entered app")

        file = request.files['file']
        #type_file = request.form['type']
        print("Step 2_"*5,"file name taken")

        # seg_my_text = text_seg()
        # personal_info = per_info()
        # work_exp=work_ex()

        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        print(filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(r"/home/nextjob/database/text_seg/", filename))
        fileName=os.path.join(r"/home/nextjob/database/text_seg/", filename)
        file_path=fileName

        pre_name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        #seg_my_text = text_seg()
        seg_text_extracted = text_seg_read_docx_and_pdf(file_path)
        print(seg_text_extracted)
        #with graph.as_default():
        #    print("_graph trying_"*10)
        self.seg_my_text.parse_resume(None, file_path, seg_text_extracted)
    ###########################persional info#####################################
        obj_class=Json_data_clean(pre_name + '.json')
        obj_class.json_clean()

        #pre_name = pre_name.replace('./database/text_seg/','')

        #personal_info = per_info()
        #x.main()
        pre_name_2 = pre_name.replace('/home/nextjob/database/text_seg/','')
        #personal_info = per_info()
        parse_file = "/home/nextjob/database/per_info/" + pre_name_2 + ".txt"
        per_info_dict=self.personal_info.parse_resume(parse_file)

        # print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<persional info>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n\n",per_info_dict,"\n\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    ################################end persional inf#############################################
    #############################education#####################################################
        obj_class=Json_data_education(pre_name + '.json')
        obj_class.json_clean_education()
        
        parse_file_edu = "/home/nextjob/database/education/" + pre_name_2 + ".txt"
        education_dict=education_parse(parse_file_edu)
    #############################end education#####################################################

    ##################################work experience########################################################
        work_txt_obj=Json_data_work(pre_name + '.json')
        work_txt_obj.json_clean_work()
        parse_file_work = "/home/nextjob/database/work_experience/" + pre_name_2 + ".txt"

        work_dict=self.work_exp.parse_work_data(parse_file_work)
    ########################################end work experience#################################################



    #################################################professional summary#######################################
        # personal_info_dict={}
        professional_json={}
        skill_json={}
        # work_json={}
        profe=" "
        main_skill=" "
        with open(str(pre_name+'.json')) as json_file:
            data = None
            data = json.load(json_file)
            professional_json['professional_info']=[None]
            skill_json['skills']={"SkillSet":" "}
            # work_json['work_experience']=[None]
            key_value=data.keys()
            for i in key_value:
                if i=='professional_info':
                    if data['professional_info'] is not None:
                        profe = " ".join(data['professional_info'])
                    else:
                        profe = " "

                    # professional_json['professional_info']=data['professional_info']
                elif i=='skills':
                    skills_list = [ ]
                    # skill_main=[]
                    main_skill=",".join(data['skills'])
                    for i in data['skills']:
                        j = None
                        j = {"Skill": i}
                        skills_list.append(j)
                        
                    # d = {"SkillKeywords": {"SkillSet": skills_list}}
                    skill_json['skills']={"SkillSet": skills_list}

                # elif i=='work_experience':
                    # print(data['work_experience'],"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwoooooooooorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkk")
                    # work_json['work_experience']=data['work_experience']
                else:
                    pass
        # print(professional_json['professional_info'],"lllllllllllllllllllll\n\n",skill_json['skills'],">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        # final_dict=jsonify(persional_info=list(per_info_dict),education_details=list(education_dict),professional_info=professional_json['professional_info'],skills=skill_json['skills'])
        # personal_info_dict['persional_info']=per_info_dict
        # education_dict.update(personal_info_dict)
        # education_dict.update(professional_json)
        # education_dict.update(skill_json)
        # education_dict.update(work_dict)
        if per_info_dict["FirstName"] and per_info_dict["LastName"] is not None:
            FUN= per_info_dict["FirstName"]+" "+per_info_dict["LastName"]
        else :
            FUN = per_info_dict["FirstName"] or per_info_dict["LastName"]
        d={"ResumeParserData":{"FullName":FUN or " ","FirstName":per_info_dict["FirstName"] or " ","LastName":per_info_dict["LastName"] or " ","DateOfBirth":per_info_dict["DateOfBirth"] or " ","Gender":per_info_dict["Gender"] or " ","MaritalStatus":per_info_dict["MaritalStatus"] or " ","Email":per_info_dict["Email"] or " ","AlternateEmail":per_info_dict["AlternateEmail"] or " ","Phone":per_info_dict["Phone"] or " ","Mobile":per_info_dict["Mobile"] or " ","Address":per_info_dict["Address"] or " ","City":per_info_dict["City"] or " ","ZipCode":per_info_dict["ZipCode"] or " ","PermanentAddress":per_info_dict["PermanentAddress"] or " ","PermanentCity":per_info_dict["PermanentCity"] or " ","PermanentZipCode":per_info_dict["PermanentZipCode"],"CurrentSalary":" ","ExpectedSalary": " ","Qualification":education_dict['Qualification'],"SegregatedQualification":education_dict['SegregatedQualification'],"Skills":main_skill,"SkillSet":skill_json['skills']["SkillSet"],"Experience":work_dict[0],"SegregatedExperience":work_dict[1],"Summary":profe or " "}}
        skill_string = json.dumps(d, indent = 4, sort_keys=False)
        with open("/home/nextjob/database/final_json/"+pre_name_2+'.json',"w") as json_file:
            json.dump(d, json_file, indent=2, sort_keys=False)
        keras.backend.clear_session()
        return jsonify(d)

#api.add_resource(process, '/process')
#@api.app.route(process, '/process')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #test = process()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5000,debug=True)
```

After running `python Integrated_app.py`,i get this error:

```
Initial time: 1.6689300537109375e-05
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 339-043-829
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2020 20:30:57] "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2020 20:31:00] "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

After running `export FLASK_APP="Integrated_app:app"` and ```flask run``, i get this error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "Integrated_app:app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 158-271-172
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 860, in run_command
    extra_files=extra_files,
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1050, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 337, in run_with_reloader
    reloader.run()
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 202, in run
    for filename in chain(_iter_module_files(), self.extra_files):
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 24, in _iter_module_files
    filename = getattr(module, "__file__", None)
  File "/home/nextjob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/home/nextjob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/home/nextjob/anaconda3/envs/irp/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras'
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

--------------------------Model Loaded-------------------------------------

Total Time Taken To Load the Model ------------------------->  0:00:03.914416 


Total Time Taken For Output of all Files ------------------------->  0:00:00.000083 

--------------------------Model Loaded-------------------------------------

Total Time Taken To Load the Model ------------------------->  0:00:03.848447 


Total Time Taken For Output of all Files ------------------------->  0:00:00.000088
```

and by using `gunicorn -w 2 'Integrated_app:app'`, i get this error:

```
[2020-07-10 20:39:23 +0530] [18644] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-07-10 20:39:23 +0530] [18644] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (18644)
[2020-07-10 20:39:23 +0530] [18644] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-10 20:39:23 +0530] [18647] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18647
[2020-07-10 20:39:23 +0530] [18651] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18651
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

--------------------------Model Loaded-------------------------------------

Total Time Taken To Load the Model ------------------------->  0:00:03.871782 


Total Time Taken For Output of all Files ------------------------->  0:00:00.000069 

Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'Integrated_app'.
[2020-07-10 20:39:30 +0530] [18647] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18647)
--------------------------Model Loaded-------------------------------------

Total Time Taken To Load the Model ------------------------->  0:00:04.019945 


Total Time Taken For Output of all Files ------------------------->  0:00:00.000088 

Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'Integrated_app'.
[2020-07-10 20:39:30 +0530] [18651] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18651)
[2020-07-10 20:39:31 +0530] [18644] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-07-10 20:39:31 +0530] [18644] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

Please let me know my mistakes and how to run it using gunicorn.
Thank you.

Comment: In your "process" class you have an app.route /process but a function (__init__) that receives a parameter ("self"), which I think messes up the flask. Maybe you can fix this by putting app.route outside the class and then calling __init__ in that function?

Comment: I did a few changes, dropped class and init (actually its only purpose was to load models before process)
Here's the changed part:
``@app.route('/process', methods=['POST','PUT'])
def post():   
    seg_my_text = text_seg()
    personal_info = per_info()
    work_exp=work_ex()``

But still there will be problem because model gets loaded at every process

Comment: Maybe its a problem with the gunicorn Procfile? I dont think I know how to fix the issue, sorry.